# Ignore any other _GET Variables

Tags: php, get

See, I have this return script which will return the user to the page they were denied access to because they aren't logged in, however it misses GET variables. Sorry if I can't explain..

For example, my url is:

`/login.php?return=/update.php?Number2=011&id=9696b8`

I want "return" to contain:

`/login.php?return=**/update.php?Number2=011&id=9696b8**`

However it thinks that "id" is a seperate get variable and misses it and gives me only:

`/login.php?return=**/update.php?Number2=011**&id=9696b8`

I understand why it's happening, just not how to prevent it.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

`rawurlencode()` is what are you searching for

[demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/1c90a.php)

result:

```
/login.php?return=%2Fupdate.php%3FNumber2%3D011%26id%3D9696b8
```

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for! Thank you! I'll accept it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the query parameter with `rawurlencode()`.

The result will then be

```
/login.php?return=%2Fupdate.php%3FNumber2%3D011%26id%3D9696b8
```